# Should "materials" and "processing agents" be plural or singular after "any" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, singular-vs-plural, countability

> 1. The products do not come into contact with any **materials or processing agents that contain** gluten.

VS.

> 2. The products do not come into contact with any **material or processing agent that contains** gluten.

Which phrase is better? Why? The goal is to state that these products are gluten-free.

My boss actually changed my first sentence into the second one, and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: Both are correct. Neither is wrong. When you consulted your English language dictionary, what did it tell you about the _uncountable noun_ "material" and the _countable noun_ "material(s)"?

Comment: Thank you P.E. Dant. My boss actually changed my first sentence into the second one, and I am trying to understand why. Saw this regarding material: According to Dictionary.com:

materials

The articles or apparatus needed to make or do something.

material

A group of ideas, facts, data, etc. that may provide the basis for or be incorporated into some integrated work.

Comment: It's important to understand the difference in English between _countable_ nouns like "material(s)" and _uncountable nouns_ like "material". Have you learned the difference between the two?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't trust that statement. I'd rather see "The product contains no gluten and has not come into contact with gluten. "  Unless the law requires it, the phrase "materials or processing agents" is simply excess verbiage.

Comment: Material is countable for this definition. [See dictionary.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/material?fallbackFrom=british-grammar) The real question is the grammar of ***any***, which can take either singular or plural nouns after it.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed - I've made some quick edits to try to highlight the specific question about English, but I'm late for work and probably mangled it. Please don't just read "which is better?" and automatically vote to close as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but the second one with "material" and "agent" in singular sounds simpler to me. To make sense, the sentence needs to be in the present perfect tense, though:

> The products have not come into contact with any material or processing
>   agent that contains gluten.

Answer (score 0):

I think in processes the products did not contact the materials or agent that contain gluten.
It may be better to say *In our processes the products did not contact the materials or agents that contain gluten.*
But I need more information.

Comment: That is a somewhat complex circumlocution that doesn't get the point across.

Comment: The OP asked which of the two suggested sentences is better, and why. There is no request for other suggestions. If brevity and clarity were the goals, both would be met by: _"The products at no time come into contact with gluten."_

Comment: Probably in their factory or processes the products are not likely to have the risk of contamination of gluten, or their processing agents do not have the risk either. Plural would be better. The original poster says that "these products are gluten-free". Then this is much better if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I were a consumer, and I read either of the two examples, I would suspect the product contained gluten. Why?  Because the the label, as Shakespeare might have written, “doth protest too much.”

“This product is gluten-free” is perfect. I would believe that.